# How do I make a UILabel with dynamically changing and looping text?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uilabel

I want to make a label that's text changes from "Loading" -> "Loading." ->"Loading.." -> "Loading..." dynamically and for as long as that label exists.

So I just created a label and added a function that I call called `animateDots` that just keeps calling itself. I had it done using `UIView.animateWithDuration()` and every completion block calls another `animateWithDuration()` until it just calls `animateDots()` and so on. But that didn't work because the text in a UILabel isn't animatable so it just animates all four labels really fast. I want it to be slow.

I tried `UIView.preformWithoutAnimation` and I also tried `UIView.beginAnimations` but I can't recall `animateDots()` without causing the app to crash. I have no idea what else to try

**Edit:** Here's how I solved it thanks to @7vikram7 's suggestion.

I created the timer right after I initialize the label, and the timer repeats. Every time the timer finishes a loop, it runs a selector, in this case `animateDots`, which changes the text. In Code:

Add this whenever you want to start the animation process:

```
loading = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,80,50))
loading.text = "Loading"
let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector:
            #selector(LoadingCell.animateDots), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timer.fire()
```

Then add this function:

```
func animateDots() {
        switch (loading.text!) {
        case "Loading...":
            loading.text = "Loading"
        case "Loading":
            loading.text = "Loading."
        case "Loading.":
            loading.text = "Loading.."
        case "Loading..":
            loading.text = "Loading..."
        default:
            loading.text = "Loading"
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use NSTimer. Schedule a timer with interval of 2 or 3 seconds which repeats. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/

Comment: Ahh that's a really good idea! I'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: can you add bit of code here?

Comment: Sure! I'll add it as a comment to the Answer I chose as the solution and as an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSTimer. Schedule a timer with interval of 2 or 3 seconds which repeats.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/

Comment: So I used this answer, the way I used it was by creating a timer that just repeats over a certain interval, and every time it repeats, it runs a selector, in this case it was `animateDots`. See my edit for the code specifics

Answer (score 2):

Copy and past into your project and change value of timer and seconds

Start timer when you want to animation of text and stop when is not in use

```
NSTimer *myticker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(set your time) target:self selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)showActivity {

    second=second-0.5; // set your second

    if (second <= 0) {
        [myticker invalidate];

    }


    if (second >= 5) {
        if ([connectingLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Connecting."]) {
            connectingLabel.text = @"Connecting..";

        }else  if ([connectingLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Connecting.."]) {
            connectingLabel.text = @"Connecting...";

        }else if ([connectingLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Connecting..."]) {
            connectingLabel.text = @"Connecting.";
        }else{
            connectingLabel.text = @"Connecting.";

        }
    }else{
        connectingLabel.text = @"";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5 Version of Wos answer**

```
    var myticker : Timer?
func LabelAnimating() {
    myticker  = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(showLoading), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func showLoading() {

    if findingTripsLbl.text == "Connecting." {
        findingTripsLbl.text = "Connecting.."
    } else if findingTripsLbl.text == "Connecting.." {
        findingTripsLbl.text = "Connecting..."
    } else if findingTripsLbl.text == "Connecting..." {
        findingTripsLbl.text = "Connecting."
    } else {
        findingTripsLbl.text = "Connecting."
    }}

func StopLoading()  {
         myticker?.invalidate()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create 4 images like that and you can set the animation for `uiimageview`. It gives the same result as you want.

Answer (score 0):

[MarqueeLabel](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel) can help you achieve this with little modification. Either you make your **Loading** text a different label and make your **DOTS** text a MarqueeLabel or you completely make all three dots different labels hiding and unhiding them respectively. The latter is a very tedious method and is highly unrecommended, hence use first.

```
pod MarqueeLabel
```

[MarqueeLabel](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel) provides this feature. Just set the class name of your label to MarqueeLabel as:

```
@IBOutlet weak var lblLocation: MarqueeLabel!
```

Set the properties according to your requirement:

1. Duration
2. FadeLength
3. MarqueeType